# if else statement running first if only

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple search page where I get values from a form. In that form I have fields for a specific date, two fields to choose two dates to search between the two selected dates, and an ID field to search by ID. When running my code only the first if statement is executed and runs as expected, but if I leave that date value empty in that field and set a value in fields after it the code doesn't do anything and gives me the handled error message "There are no results for your search".

```
    if (isset($_POST['date_search_on']))
{    $search_on = $_POST['date_search_on'];
      $qry = " SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '$search_on' "; 
      $result = mysqli_query ($con, $qry);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <=0) {
                           echo 'There are no results for your search'; }
                           } // end first if

      else if (isset($_POST['date_search_after'],$_POST['date_search_before']  )) {

        $search_after = $_POST['date_search_after'];
        $search_before = $_POST ['date_search_before'];
        $qry = " SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '$search_after' AND '$search_before'";
        $result = mysqli_query ($con, $qry);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <=0) {
                           echo 'There are no results for your search'; }
      } // end 2nd if 

       else if (isset($_POST['id_search'])) {
        $search_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id_search']);
        $qry = " SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$search_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query ($con, $qry);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <=0) {
                           echo 'There are no results for your search'; }
       } //end 3rd if
```

I tried replacing `if(isset())` with `if ($_POST['variable']) !==NULL` and got the same result. Thank you!

adding the form's code as requested

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date_search_on">Show results sent on</label>
     <input type="date" id="date_search_on" class="form-control" name="date_search_on">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <h3>Show sent</h3>
       <label for="date_search_after">After</label>
       <input type="date" id="date_search_after" class="form-control" name="date_search_after" >
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="date_search_before">and before</label>
       <input type="date" id="date_search_before" class="form-control" name="date_search_before">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="id"> ID</label>
       <input type="text" id="id" class="form-control" name="id_search">
     </div>

     <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"></input> 
  </form>
```

Comment: What are your form inputs?

Comment: try to var_dump($variable); This will give you an output of your variable: `$_POST['date_search_on']` and you can see if even anything is being passed. On your `mysqli_query ($con, $qry);` add `mysqli_query ($con, $qry)or die("error: ".mysqli_error($con));` this will give you any errors that are resulting in your querys

Comment: `<=0)` how can something be less than zero?

Comment: @Fred-ii- - <=0 is like Less Than Jake. http://www.lessthanjake.com/ :)

Comment: I've added the form's code
@DarkSideKillaz I did print_r($_POST) and everything I type in the form is actually passed to the $_POST array

Comment: @user2182349 *hehe* ;-)

Comment: this line is wrong also `$search_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lead_id_search']);` needs to have `$con`: i would also use  `if(!empty($_POST['date_search_on']))` instead of is set. Even if nothing is entered in a form the `$_POST` will still see it as `" "`

Comment: I sincerely doubt that this question is (completely) solved. Your `else if (isset($_POST['id_search'])) {...}` will fail, then you'll either be asking for more help or we'll be seeing another question from you about it.

Comment: @DarkSideKillaz Yes I noticed that and fixed it, i'll update the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Everything is working perfectly now. And I'm not sure why you think it would fail?

Comment: `$search_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id_search']);` you mean to tell me that this works? I highly doubt that. RTM on this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Like mentioned above your comment, it is now fixed and question has been updated.

Comment: yeah well what you posted originally and what was posted in answers didn't equal to a solution, not in my opinion and I'm sure many share my view on this. We call 'em as we see 'em. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42869769/1

Comment: @Fred-ii-your argument while valid, is beside the point. You pointed it out and it was fixed, thank you. I'm not sure where you're getting at. Anything else that may break the code?

Comment: you're open to one serious sql injection; use a prepared statement on everything

Comment: @Fred-ii-Yeah I still gotta look up how to prevent sql injections with prepared statements. I thought escaping users' input with mysqli_real_escape_string() would be enough. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of **isset**, use **empty**,

```
if (!empty($_POST['date_search_on']))
```

The **empty** function will return true if the field has not been set, or if it contains null, false or an empty string.

Note that this tests for *not* empty, since you want to use the value if it isn't empty.

The data is probably being sent, however if you left the input blank, it is set but empty.

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {}
```

to check if your script was POSTed.

If additional data was passed, $_POST will not be empty, otherwise it will.

You can use empty method to check if it contains data.

```
if ( !empty($_POST) ) {}
```

Comment: well don't who is that, i wish to have a flag to report for down vote as well.

Answer (score -1):

The error raises because when `date_search_on` is empty, db query is comparing value of `lead_date` against `''`, then because it finds no row, first if evaluates to true.

You should change first `if`'s condition check to let it test other `if`s when `date_search_on` is left empty. so change your `$qry` assignment like this:

```
$search_on = trim($_POST['date_search_on']);
if (empty($qry)){
  $qry = " SELECT * FROM leads"; 
}else{
  $qry = " SELECT * FROM leads WHERE lead_date = '$search_on' "; 
}
$result = mysqli_query ($con, $qry);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <=0) {
  echo 'There are no results for your search'; 
}
```

Comment: Trimming could've helped but I used the !empty() function and it worked. Thanks for your answer.